# Set the year of a java date

Tags: java, date, calendar

I am trying to set the year of a `java.util.Date`.

he time stamp I need to parse does not include the year so I did this:

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat logTimeStampFormat = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

boolean isAfterRefDate (String line, Date refDate) {        
    try {
        Date logTimeStamp = logTimeStampFormat.parse(line);
        logTimeStamp.setYear(2012);      // But this is deprecated!
        return logTimeStamp.after(refDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // Handle exception
    }        
}
```

To avoid using a deprecated method, I do like this:

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat logTimeStampFormat = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

private static Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

boolean isAfterRefDate (String line, Date refDate) {
    try {
        Date logTimeStamp = logTimeStampFormat.parse(line);
        cal.setTime(logTimeStamp);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);
        logTimeStamp = cal.getTime();            
        return logTimeStamp.after(refDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // Handle exception
    }        
}
```

I just don't think that this is the best way to solve this problem.  I have to first set the calendar object properly and then get the date object back from it while earlier I could just modify the date object directly.

Can someone suggest a better approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can someone suggest a better approach.

Sure - try to avoid using `Date` and `Calendar` in the first place. Use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead, which is much better.

Setting the year on a `Date` is an inherently ambiguous operation - what time zone is this year meant to be? What would you expect to happen if you're setting a year of 2013 on a previous date of February 29th 2012?

Using Joda Time will make your code much clearer in terms of what kind of data you're *really* expecting. You can always convert to/from `Date` and `Calendar` at API boundaries if you really need to.

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

> Can someone suggest a better approach?

Yes, use the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

The [Answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11966856/642706) was correct but is now outdated, as the Joda-Time team advises migration to the java.time classes.

### `MonthDay` & `LocalTime`

We can parse that input string as two separate objects, a `MonthDay` and a `LocalTime`. The first is obviously a month and a day-of-month but without any year so it is not a complete date. The second represents a time-of-day but without any date and without any time zone.

```
String input = "Sep 21 12:34:56.123";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "MMM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" );

MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse ( input , f );
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse ( input , f );

System.out.println ( "md: " + md + " | lt: " + lt );
```

> md: --09-21 | lt: 12:34:56.123

### `LocalDateTime`

We can add in a year, stir altogether, and get a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( ld , lt );
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

This is still not an actual moment, not a point on the timeline. Without the context of an offset-from-UTC or a time zone, a `LocalDateTime` has no meaning.

Apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Now we have a meaningful moment, a point on the timeline.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z );
```

Comment: Been seeing your answers from a long time, It looks like you are the chief marketing manager of java time! ;) (Oh, and, All your answers are great)